# Can't add bar button item to navigationBar in detail viewController using Storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I am adding an item to navigationBar in Main viewController, it works well.
When I am adding an item to navigationBar in detail ViewController, I drag the item to ViewController, but it doesn't work, I can only add it to the top  or bottom of the ViewController. And when I run the app, there is no item in the screen.

[image]

How can I add an item to navigationBar in detail ViewController by storyboard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add NavigationItem for your DetailsViewController, and then select Bar Button Item, and drag it to a NavigationItem which you've just added. [image]

Comment: @swordjoy if worked, then please upvote and mark as solved :)